# Could you add a synonym from scikits-learn to scikit-learn?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The name of the http://scikit-learn.org project is just [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) but people keep getting confused as the former python package name was `scikits.learn` hence they tend to use the [scikits-learn](/questions/tagged/scikits-learn) tag as well (although I just retagged those questions manually).

Comment: You should thank @RobertHarvey; I just added [meta-tag:stackoverflow] to the question, as it is about Stack Overflow tags.

Comment: Alright @RobertHarvey too then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed (posting this wiki answer to get the question off the unanswered page, please upvote).